# Selenium Webriver : Issue with the Menu and Submenu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written script for one demo eCommerce application and I am facing problem with the menu and sub menu. As i am running the script it takes me to the login page and at the same time it checks for the product category and clicks on the submenu. But my requirement is after login it should check the product category and then it should click the submenu.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("account")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

    WebElement elemnt= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"));
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(elemnt).build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("iPads")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("account_logout")).click();
    driver.quit();
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: So what is the problem with your code??

Comment: what you are checking in product category? as you mentioned that " after login it should check the product category "

Answer (score 0):

To interact with "select" elements (dropdowns) you should use the select command. Hopefully something like this in Java (the C# syntax I'm familiar with is a bit different):

```
driver.select("linkText="Product Category", "label=iPads");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("account")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

Thread.sleep(8000);
WebElement elemnt= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product Category"));
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elemnt).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("iPads")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("account_logout")).click();
driver.quit();
}
```